# Using text in front of "Name:" in filename

Tags: vba, ms-word

After I am done typing a Word document (in my case a clinic note), I run the following VBA to automatically save PDF and Word copies of the document.

The filename contains:
Date + The first 2 words in the document. (eg. "2022-07-11 Timothy Dalton")

I want the filename to contain:
Date + The first 2 words following the text "Patient Name:" in the document.

So,
Currently I need the first two words of the document to be the patient name. After (hopefully) the VBA code is modified, I will be able to write a more proper beginning:

> Dear Dr. xyz,
> It was a pleasure seeing Mr. Timothy Dalton to my clinic. Details as under:
>
> Patient Name: Timothy Dalton
> Age: 125 years
> Gender: Male
>
> .....
> ...
> ...
> ......
> ......
>
> Sincerely,
> Dr. Yes.

Current code:

```vb
Sub PDF_Sv_And_Pr()
    Dim InitialWords As Range
    Set InitialWords = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Words(1).Start, _
            End:=ActiveDocument.Words(2).End)
            
    Dim Dt As String: Dt = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")

    With ActiveDocument
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "G:\My Drive\Clinic Visits\" & Dt & " " & InitialWords & ".pdf", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "G:\My Drive\Clinic Visits\" & Dt & " " & InitialWords & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    End With

    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered how the name will be entered in the word doc if it is e.g. "Richard Van der Valk"? "Dear Mr. Richard Van" may seem unprofessional.

Comment: Put a [field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-edit-and-view-fields-in-word-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb) where the name must be. Type into it when you need to. Refer to its contents from the code via `ActiveDocument.Fields`. Or put a [textbox](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b).

Comment: you could also use a tagged Content Control and captuer the contents of that CC.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a bookmark (called **PName** in this example) around the patient name, you can use this code:

```
Sub PDF_Sv_And_Pr()
    Dim PatientName As String
    Dim Dt As String: Dt = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")

    PatientName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName").Range.Text

    With ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs2 "G:\My Drive\Clinic Visits\" & Dt & " " & PatientName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        .SaveAs2 "G:\My Drive\Clinic Visits\" & Dt & " " & PatientName & ".docx" = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName").Range.Text & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    End With

    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tom says, you'll run into problems with multi-word names if you're assuming the name consists of only two words. Presumably, your patients also have patient IDs, which you could use as part of the filename instead of their names. Nevertheless, rather than limiting things to just the first two words after 'Patient Name:' you could capture the rest of that line. For example:

```
Sub PDF_Sv_And_Prn()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim PatientName As String, Dt As String
Const Path As String = "G:\My Drive\Clinic Visits\": Dt = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")
With ActiveDocument
  PatientName = " " & Trim(Split(Split(.Range.Text, "Patient Name:")(1), vbCr)(0))
  .SaveAs2 Path & Dt & PatientName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
  .SaveAs2 Path & Dt & PatientName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
  .PrintOut
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PDF_SAVE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim PatientName As String, Dt As String

myFolderName = Environ("userprofile") & "\SP\Reklamace - Reklamace\"
 Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objOutlook  As Object
    Dim objMailItem As Object

    
    With ActiveDocument
    strFileName = Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docm", ".pdf")
  Dl = " " & Trim(Split(Split(.Range.Text, "Dodací list:")(1), vbCr)(0))
  Shipment = " " & Trim(Split(Split(.Range.Text, "Shipment (ASTRO WMS):")(1), vbCr)(0))
  RP = "__RP"
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 myFolderName & RP & Dl & Shipment & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatText, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFileName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) ' 0 = olMailItem
    With objMailItem
        .Subject = "& RP & Dl &"
        .Body = "My Message"
        .To = "jakub.r@o.cz"
        .Attachments.Add strFileName
        .Display
    End With

    Kill strFileName

    Set objMailItem = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End With
  Dim bExists As Boolean
    Dim MyPrint As Dialog

    ' ensure our doc variable exists
    bExists = False
    For Each varItem In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
        If varItem.Name = "Copies" Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next varItem
    
    ' initialize document variable if doesn't exist
    If Not bExists Then
        ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
          Name:="Copies", LinkToContent:=False, _
          Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, Value:=1
    End If

    Set MyPrint = Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
    With MyPrint
        .NumCopies = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Copies")
        .Show
    End With

    ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Copies") = _
      MyPrint.NumCopies
      
    
    Dim windowsObject As Object
    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.